# Views block doesn't display all rows

Tags: views, entities

what can be wrong if my view renders only 4 list elements? I have pager disabled - displaying all items, no offset, $view->total_rows is 21. I have no views alter. Have you any ideas where to find fix for that behaviour?

Comment: put in a `print_r($view->result, TRUE)` somewhere and see what might be going on there.

Comment: I have used dpm() and I get 4 elements array in results while in admin everything is OK.

Comment: then I'd ignore `$view->total_rows` and instead use `count($view->result)` re: http://drupal.org/node/623498

Comment: /me is dummy. In Views settings page check to always display Master view. I had Master view hidden and there were 4 rows set so it's not problem - only I should learn more.